# How to fix 'No match for operator[]' error (c++)

Tags: c++

So I was given this array:
`int arr[] = {60,70,30,15,17,80,16,75,90,85,40,75};`

I have to "fit" as much elements in this array as possible while having their sum being less than 500 (basically removing the biggest one until sum is less than 500).

This is what i've tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int largestOfArray(int number[]);

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int arr[] = {60,70,30,15,17,80,16,75,90,85,40,75};
    list<int> ar(arr,arr+12);

    for (i = 0; i < 12;i++) 
        sum += arr[i];

    while (sum > 500)
        ar.remove(largestOfArray(arr[12]));

    for (i = 0; i < 12;i++)
        sum += arr[i];

    for (i = 0;i < 12; i++)
        cout << arr[i];

    cout << sum;
    return 0;
}

int largestOfArray(int number[12]){
    int i = 0;
    int largest = number[0];
    for (i = 0;i < 12;i++){
        if (largest < number[i]) largest = number[i];
    }
    return largest;
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::list' and 'int')

I know it has something to do with the `ar.remove(largestOfArray(ar[12]));` 
but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Use a `std::vector`. *Not* a list, nor a C-style array.

Comment: @drescherjm  well then i got this error:cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::list<int>' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'int largestOfArray(int*)'|

Comment: Sorry I mixed up `arr` and `ar`. This is one reason to use good naming of variables.

Comment: @Alpha make sure you have clear variable names. This would get even the more experienced programmers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you use both `ar` and `arr`, while `arr` is an array and `ar` is a list. This is both confusing to the reader and (it turns out) to the code author.

In C++, std::list doesn't have random access. You cannot use `ar[]`, since operator[] is not defined for lists. Further, `largestOfArray` expects an array, not a list. You probably intended to use `arr` there instead of `ar`.

Answer (score 2):

**Using std::list answer:**

1. Make largestOfArray receive the list
2. Make largestOfArray return the largest value
3. To remove an element you should call ar.erase(find(value));

**Advanced answer:**

There are a stack of things that can be improved here.

1. Generally prefer std::vector over std::list
2. Use std::accumulate to calculate the sum
3. Your code is fragile, and doesn't handle differing array sizes (use std::size)
4. std::list elements cannot be accessed by index
5. std::max_element can be used to find the maximum element
6. If you can't have duplicates, use std::set rather that std::vector
7. If you don't care about ordering, I'd use a vector, (reverse) sort the vector, and then keep popping off the back of the vector while your sum is above 500

Code that you don't write can't have bugs in it (generally speaking). You should take a look at all the functions inside the <algorithm> header to see what can help you.

Comment: 1. List has its benefits, list element is removed faster than `std::vector`. read this: https://thispointer.com/difference-between-vector-and-list-in-c/

Comment: yeah im new to c++ so..i kinda have no idea what you're talking about xd
i will try to look these up later though when i know more about c++
thx btw :)

Comment: @Alpha, stick with what you know. and read this: https://thispointer.com/difference-between-vector-and-list-in-c/

Comment: @Gox I am aware that list has benefits which is why I said generally (by the way, it's faster to remove from the end of a vector than the end of a list).

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in you your while condition. see `ar[12]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is passing array:

You do not pas array as follow:

```
function(arr[10])
```

Above line passes 11th element to `function()`

To pass entire array you pass the name of the array.

```
function(arr)
```

In your case:

```
largestOfArray(arr[12])
```

passes 13th element of `arr`

this should be:

```
largestOfArray(arr)
```

in this line:

```
while (sum > 500) ar.remove(largestOfArray(arr[10]));
```

EDIT:
Now that I see what is going on, `std::list` has no operator `[]` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list why doesn't it have it? This might help: https://thispointer.com/difference-between-vector-and-list-in-c/

basicly

`largestOfArray()` accepts array, so I do not know did you mean to pass `arr` or `ar`.

Comment: i meant to pass arr, but for some reason i messed up

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors in your code.

- Please take a look how a list is defined in C++.
- Check what is a static array, what are dynamic arrays.
- Use {} for every loop. Especially for a beginner it will be more easy to read and to find errors.
- Check how to pass arguments to functions in C++.

Here is a simple solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int largestInList(const list<int> &numbers);
int sumOfList(const list<int> &numbers);

int main()
{
    int i,c = 0;
    int arr[] = {60,70,30,15,17,80,16,75,90,85,40,75};
    list<int> mylist(arr,arr+12);
    int sum = sumOfList(mylist);
    while (sum > 500)
    {
        int largest = largestInList(mylist);
        for (list<int>::iterator i=mylist.begin(); i!=mylist.end(); i++)
        {
            if (*i == largest)
            {
                mylist.erase(i);
                break;
            }

        }
        sum = sumOfList(mylist);
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}

int sumOfList(const list<int> &numbers)
{
    int sum = 0;
    //For Loop before C++11:
    //for (list<int>::const_iterator it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it)
    //{
    //    sum += *it;
    //}
    for (const auto &lel : numbers) 
        sum += lel;
    return sum;
}

int largestInList(const list<int> &numbers){
    list<int>::const_iterator it = numbers.begin();
    int largest = *it;
    for (const auto &n : numbers){
        if (largest < n) largest = n;
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Comment: add also how can you display the number in the array after being removed?

Comment: Please tell me which part you do not understand

Comment: If you want to display the numbers in the array, you just need to loop over your list, like I did it in the function sumOfList and largestInList. Then you use e.g. cout to output the values.

Comment: the for loop in the two functions

Comment: like the constant auto and '&n' and '&lel'

Comment: This is a range based for loop. A new feature in C++11. Look here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/range-based-loop-c/

If it does not compile, you did to tell your compiler to use C++11. E.g.
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp

Comment: The const you use to make clear that you only want to read the values but not to override the values

Comment: The auto keyword is used that you do not explicitly need to set the type. The compiler knows automatically that he needs to use 'int' as the type in this case. So you could just replace int with auto.

Comment: '&' means you will take the reference:
int a = 5;
int b = a;
int &c = a;

in the case of b you copy the value of a into the memory of b. In the case of c you just take the reference of a. Taking the reference is less computational effort than copying.
If you do not care about computational effort, you can just omit the '&'.

Comment: Before C++11 you for loop would have looked like that:
for (list<int>::const_iterator it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it)
{
    sum += *it;
}